# How can add loading indicator when init tinymce-react editor

Tags: reactjs, tinymce, rich-text-editor

I am working on React project, which is using tinymce-react as an Editor. What I am looking for is the way to add loading indicator when initialize Editor component. Because it would take a bit time to be shown completely on the UI. So I want to make user experience better by adding loading indicator at that time.

Here is my code:

```
                  <div className={classes.richTextEditor}>
                        <p>Loading ...</p>
                        <Editor
                          apiKey="mj2rbon8mj1dl5roh4pz7rxfhbmjbhri3a97750nc3l4pvjy"
                          value={value}
                          onEditorChange={handleEditorChange}
                          init={{
                            height: 500,
                            menubar: false,
                            plugins: [
                              'advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor',
                              'searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen',
                              'insertdatetime media table paste code help wordcount',
                            ],
                            toolbar:
                              'undo redo | formatselect | bold italic backcolor | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | removeformat | link image',
                            content_css: [
                              '//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,300i,400,400i',
                              '//www.tiny.cloud/css/codepen.min.css',
                            ],
                          }}
                          initialValue={value}
                        />
                 </div>
```

I am looking into the documentation of that library, I expected something like `loading={onLoad}` but seems cannot find any clue for doing that :(.

Any help would be appreciated.